# Reconhecer texto de data no formato brasileiro

Tags: php, cakephp, data

Alguém sabe alguma forma de reconhecer texto de datas brasileiras como, hoje, amanhã, 30/04... no **PHP** usando a função `strtotime` ou no **CakePHP** usando `CakeTime`.

Estou tentando ter o mesmo resultado usando `strtotime('amanhã')` de quando é usado `strtotime('tomorrow')`, e principalmente em datas apenas com dia e mês como `strtotime('03/04')` não ser reconhecido como 04 de Março e sim 03 de Abril.

Comment: Não é assim, amigo. As funções são apenas no dialeto `inglês`, você passando o parametro em português a função não irá funcionar. Agora, respondendo essa primeira dúvida, qual é a segunda? Tudo existe um padrão, consulta a documentação http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Já viu este link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098968/how-to-display-datetime-form-mysql-using-cakephp-3-0

Comment: Eu tenho conhecimento disso @juniorb2ss, mas estou procurando saber se existe alguma forma de receber datas traduzidas para que eu possa usar isso em um campo de busca no banco de dados, caso não exista eu consigo me virar criando algo mais simples.

Comment: Não, isso não existe. Você pode fazer um array associativo com o que é dialeto em português e o que é em inglês. Essa biblioteca poderá te ajudar melhor na abstração de datas: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/